# erro ao compilar C++

Tags: c++

olá, estou tentando compilar um programa em C++ para um trabalho da faculdade mais toda hora da erro no printf, inclusive eu coloquei o mesmo codigo no devc++ e persiste, alguem pode ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Edite a pergunta e poste o código como texto, e o erro que ocorre, evite postar imagem do código [por isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485). Depois dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para mais informações úteis.

Answer (score 3):

Repare que vc está colocando uma virgula no lugar de um ponto e virgula

em `float v1,v2,v3,vt,vta,` deveria ser `float v1,v2,v3,vt,vta;`.

Answer (score 1):

Na declaração das suas variáveis, na FLOAT você finalizou com uma "," e não um ";"

Troque a "," por um ";" e compile novamente.

Comment: opá funcionou troquei os pontos de lugar, agora quando eu executo , quando vou digitar no caso o nome, ele finaliza , mas se eu colocar numero ele continua rodando, adicionei os prints novos.

Comment: Muda sua variavel nome, coloca ela assim `char nome[50];`